# Can't provision iOS 5 Beta device with Xcode 4.1

Tags: provisioning, ios5, xcode4.2

I had to re-install iOS and decided to run the new beta 5 which is out. All went fine during the process except I have a project running in Xcode 4.1 and want to provision my iOS 5 device but it's not showing up when I plug it into my MBP. I setup it up in the developers portal side of things at it shows my device as provisioned.

I figure it's my iOS 5 beta not being backwards compatible with the version of Xcode I'm using but I would like to be wrong about this.

Any tips? advice?

Also posted on the Apple Developers Forum if anyone wants to answer there

Comment: No, your xcode is not forward compatible with iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As iOS 5.0 and Xcode 4.2 are both under NDA, I'd suggest you're best placed to raise this question on the Apple dev forums.

Comment: Sorry fixed question it's xCode 4.1 and I understand the NDA but this is a provisioning question not code. maybe this would be a better question on the Apple Dev Forums...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this question is you'll need Xcode 4.2. It's a good time to move to 4.2 as Preview 7 is fairly stable.